# What are the data catalog option available in open source

Tags: metadata, catalog

I would like to know which is the best data catalog available which serves the following requirements.

- Open source
- Highly available behind load balancer
- Describes the dataset
- Can describes the data inside the datasets, Ability to have option to describe the fields inside the data
- Data set searchable

I looked at ckan and was really impressed but it did not offer describing fields inside the datasets

Is there any other good tool for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually extend the CKAN and mold it as per your needs. CKAN is a very versatile and flexible product.

e.g. for describing fields inside CKAN you can use
https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-scheming

or you can create your own extension by following the documentation.
https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/

Comment: Awesome Thank you so much. If you have worked on this, I have one more question. I will post a seperate question this. will post the link

Comment: Can you please answer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568270/is-data-in-solr-backed-by-postgres-in-ckan. I am new to ckan and exploring using it before making it ready for the company to be used

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Lyft's open source data catalog and discovery tool called "Amundsen"?

https://github.com/lyft/amundsen

https://eng.lyft.com/open-sourcing-amundsen-a-data-discovery-and-metadata-platform-2282bb436234

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the data catalog part of the engrafo-solution (engrafo.eu)

Open source (free plan for 10 users)
Highly available behind load balancer (?)
Describes the dataset (yes)
Can describes the data inside the datasets, Ability to have option to describe the fields inside the data (yes)
Data set searchable (yes)

[a demo on the data catalog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=caaNxTOYtnE)