# Is data in solr backed by postgres in ckan

Tags: postgresql, solr, ckan

I would like to create a high availability ckan in Azure. I know I can have a postgres as a service and rediss as a service, I can have ckan run behind a load balancer, only thing that bothers me is solr. Since there is no Solr as a service in Azure, how can I make sure my solr instance is highly available.

Does ckan keeps data in postgres and a duplicate of that data in solr for indexing? If yes then, that will help me as if anytime my solr instance goes does in a VM (rarely) I will create new one and replicate the data from postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can have SOLR with HA configuration using the SOLR Zookeeper

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble.html#SettingUpanExternalZooKeeperEnsemble-SettingupaZooKeeperEnsemble

Secondly, you can always reindex the SOLR in CKAN using the following command:-

https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/maintaining/paster.html#search-index-rebuild-search-index

Comment: Awesome, reindexing will work. I would not go for the first one, as it requires more resources.